# How to delete spreadsheets from hotmail

Tags: onedrive, outlook.com

I have a hotmail account.  When I click on the 16 dot square in the top left, it presents me with a whole bunch of tools.  If I then click on excel, it opens excel and lists all the sheets I have previously created.  Some of them are noddy ones which I would like to discard but I can't find a delete button.  If I select a sheet, it just opens.

Do I have to use another application or come in through a different route to delete the excel sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the 3-dot on the right of the filename. There is a new entry that shows `Delete`.

[image]

If it doesn't appear for you, Click on the 3-dot, then Open. Select `Open file location`. A new page will open. Find your file on the list. Select it. On the top, you should see a Delete button.

[image]